# What is this style of matrix algebra notation called and what does it mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

1. $[T ]^{b}_{b'}$
2. $[T ]_{b'}$
3. [ ]$_{b}$

Lets suppose $T$ is s a linear map from $V$ to $W$, and $b'$ and $b$ are bases in $V$ and $W$ respectively. I would like to know what this notation means in each case and how it is read (like "$T(v)$" is read aloud as: "T of v"). I have a shakey idea of what it means but I'd like a definitive explanation so that I can have a solid understanding.

I'd also be very grateful if someone can also point me to some resource that covers matrix representation of linear maps that uses this notation; as I couldn't find any --again, I don't know what this style of notation is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[T]$ is the matrix representative of the linear map $T$ in whatever basis is obvious, usually the standard basis. $[T]_{b}^{b'}$ is the matrix representative of $T$ which takes coordinates in the basis $b$ and gives coordinates in the basis $b'$.